# Error when trying to return custom facet data in JSON format

Tags: xdb

I have created some custom facets where I store some data.   I would like to display this data on the User Profile but I am running into issues.

I am using this link as a guide to set this up: http://reyrahadian.com/2016/08/27/sitecore-8-extending-experience-profile-part-2-displaying-contact-facet-simple-properties/

My *HttpRouteConfig.cs* file looks like:

```cs
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;

namespace MySite.Presentation
{
    public class HttpRouteConfig
    {
        public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes, args);
        }

        protected virtual void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes, PipelineArgs args)
        {
            routes.MapHttpRoute("customcontact_customfields", "sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/{contactId}/customfields", (object)new
            {
                controller = "CustomFields",
                action = "GetCustomFields"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My controller looks like:

```cs
using MySite.Models.Utility;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Cintel.ContactService;
using Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MySite.Presentation.Controllers
{

    [AuthorizedReportingUserFilter]
    public class CustomFieldsController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public object GetCustomFields(Guid contactId)
        {
            try
            {
                var contactManager = GetContactManager();
                var contact = contactManager.LoadContactReadOnly(contactId);
                if (contact == null)
                {
                    Log.Info("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.CustomFieldsController.GetCustomFields: Contact not found!", this);
                    throw new ContactNotFoundException();
                }
                var customFacet = contact.GetFacet<IContactCompanyInfo>(ContactCompanyInfo.FACET_NAME);
                Log.Info("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.CustomFieldsController.GetCustomFields: Company: " + customFacet.Company + " Industry: " + customFacet.Industry + " Sub Industry: " + customFacet.SubIndustry + " Revenue Range: " + customFacet.RevenueRange, this);
                return customFacet;
            }
            catch (ContactNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Log.Error("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.CustomFieldsController.GetCustomFields", ex, this);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static ContactManager GetContactManager()
        {
            var contactManager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;
            Assert.IsNotNull(contactManager, "Could not create instance of ContactManager");
            return contactManager;
        }
    }
}
```

My Javascript file looks like:

```js
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/DataProviderHelper.js", "/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/CintelUtl.js"], function (sc, providerHelper, cintelUtil) {
    var app = sc.Definitions.App.extend({
        initialized: function () {
            var localUrl = "/customfields/";

            providerHelper.setupHeaders([
                { urlKey: localUrl }
            ]);

            var url = sc.Contact.baseUrl + localUrl;
            var $that = this;

            providerHelper.initProvider(this.AdditionalInfoDataProvider, "", url, this.AdditionalInfoTabMessageBar);
            providerHelper.getData(this.AdditionalInfoDataProvider,
                $.proxy(function (jsondata) {
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.CompanyValue, jsondata.Company, true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.IndustryValue, jsondata.Industry, true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.SubIndustryValue, jsondata.SubIndustry, true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.RevenueRangeValue, jsondata.RevenueRange, true);
                }));
        }
    });
    return app;
});
```

When I try to reference: https://stage.mysite.com/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/3187658b-b035-4d2e-b348-7e98aed90990/customfields

I get the super-helpful response of:

> { "Message": "An error has occurred." }

You might note that I have some logging in my controller.   I can tell that I am at least getting the controller to call because I see the Company Name, etc. written into the logs when I call the above URL.

Any ideas?

I am running Sitecore 8.1 Update 2.

---

Update: Per suggestion, I turned off customErrors and now I get:

> { "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json'.", "ExceptionType":
>   "System.InvalidOperationException", "StackTrace": null,
>   "InnerException": { "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "Self referencing loop detected for property
>   'parent' with type 'MySite.Models.Utility.ContactCompanyInfo'. Path
>   'members[0]'.", "ExceptionType":
>   "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException", "StackTrace": "   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object&
>   memberValue)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
>   writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
>   effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"
>   } }

---

Update 2:  This is what my facet looks like:

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using System;

namespace MySite.Models.Utility
{
    public interface IContactCompanyInfo : IFacet
    {
        string Company { get; set; }
        string RevenueRange { get; set; }
        string Industry { get; set; }
        string SubIndustry { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ContactCompanyInfo : Facet, IContactCompanyInfo
    {
        public const string FACET_NAME = "Company Info";
        private const string FIELD_COMPANY = "Company";
        private const string FIELD_INDUSTRY = "Industry";
        private const string FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY = "SubIndustry";
        private const string FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE = "RevenueRange";

        public ContactCompanyInfo()
        {
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_COMPANY);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_INDUSTRY);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE);
        }
        public string Company
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_COMPANY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_COMPANY, value); }
        }

        public string Industry
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_INDUSTRY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_INDUSTRY, value); }
        }

        public string SubIndustry
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY, value); }
        }

        public string RevenueRange
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the route config is needed. Instead, I believe you want to add the controller to the list of "allowedControllers" in the <sitecore><api><services> node.

Comment: Do you have customErrors turned on? Setting it to off should give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: @GeoffWarren Hmm interesting... turned it off and it throws the error shown in my update above.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code - Can you post your Facet concrete class? and IElement concrete class?

Comment: @PeteNavarra you were reading my mind.  I just did.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code, var contact = contactManager.LoadContactReadOnly(contactId); Always returning null value. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This magically fixed itself on Friday.   I am not really sure why or how, but I am not complaining.

Comment: I am getting the same issue, do you have any idea how you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

According to that error you have a self-referencing loop in your facet object that is breaking the serializer.

You can configure JSON.NET to ignore reference loops through serialization settings. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationsettings.htm

Comment: "You could also project the facet to a new object" ... not sure what you mean there.

Comment: I also don't understand how there is a self-referencing loop in the Facet?  The facet is pretty simple -- just four pieces of data.

Comment: Forget the projection part, I was being dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I have serialized Facets Values using Newtonsoft.Json and after that, it works fine for me. Here Newtonsoft.Json will serialize and give you a string object so before return, it to the JSON data you need to parse it as below:

```
try
{
    var contactManager = GetContactManager();
    var contact = contactManager.LoadContactReadOnly(contactId);
    if (contact == null)
    {
        Log.Info("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.CustomFieldsController.GetCustomFields: Contact not found!", this);
        throw new ContactNotFoundException();
    }
    var customFacet = contact.GetFacet<IContactCompanyInfo>(ContactCompanyInfo.FACET_NAME);
    Log.Info("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.CustomFieldsController.GetCustomFields: Company: " + customFacet.Company + " Industry: " + customFacet.Industry + " Sub Industry: " + customFacet.SubIndustry + " Revenue Range: " + customFacet.RevenueRange, this);
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new XdbJsonContractResolver(client.Model, serializeFacets: true, serializeContactInteractions: true),
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
    };
    return Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customFacet, serializerSettings));
}
catch (ContactNotFoundException ex)
{
    Log.Error("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.CustomFieldsController.GetCustomFields", ex, this);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Message);
}
```

You can find serialization setting more details from [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/serialize-xconnect-entities-using-json-net.html).